# How to get packet data/payload captured through pyshark in python

Tags: python, packet, pyshark

```
import pyshark as py
cap=py.LiveCapture(interface="Wi-Fi")
for i in cap:
cap.sniff(timeout=5)
print(cap.payload)
print(i.payload)
```

In
`print(i.payload)`
and
`print(cap.payload)`
I am getting error
I want to check the payload or data of a captured packet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print tcp payload from Pcap file with pyshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673841/print-tcp-payload-from-pcap-file-with-pyshark)